# jmeter mail reader sampler connection issues

Tags: email, jmeter

I am trying to check my gmail with a mail reader sampler in `jmeter` and enabled both `imap` and `pop3` in my gmail account.

Everytime I try to connect to gmail, I keep getting this error:

> Response message: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
>   `nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

This is my query: 
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkQ85.png)

I tried both `SSL` and `TLS` option at the bottom. I tried adding and leaving out the  port. Also experimented with leaving out "@gmail.com" portion in my email address. And also wrote the protocol as pop3 and as pop3s. Not sure why it won't work.

I am on a corporate wifi, I don't know if that could be the thing causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure JMeter can connect the Internet. To validate it add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and insert any Internet IP address or hostname in the relevant input, i.e. `example.com`

If the request succeeds - double check Mail Reader Sampler settings. If request is failing - most likely you're sitting behind corporate proxy and need to c[onfigure JMeter to use it](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).

---

In regards to the Mail Reader Sampler configuration for POP3 protocol should look as follows:

- Protocol: `pop3s`
- Host: `pop.googlemail.com`
- Port: `995`
- Username: `username@gmail.com`
- Password: your account password
- Security Settings: `Use SSL`

You may also need to [turn on access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in your Google Account settings

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response! It was a wifi issue so I had to use the public wifi offerred by the company to make it work.

Also, note that I got it to work with `imap` instead. Here are the configs I used:

Protocol: `imaps`

Host: `imap.gmail.com`

Port: `993`

Username: `username (don't include @gmail.com)`

Password: `your account password`

Security Settings: `Use SSL`

Comment: Additionally I had to check `Trust al certificates` on the Mail Reader Sampler. Key was to NOT include `@gmail.com`. Thank you very much!