# Mail Reader Sampler connection error

Tags: performance, jmeter, beanshell

I got an error during execution of Mail Reader sampler. I also tried IMAP but still got the error, any solutions, please ?

```
 Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1  
Sample Start: 2017-06-02 12:20:45 EDT  
Load time: 21015  
Connect Time: 0  
Latency: 0  
Size in bytes: 0  
Sent bytes:0  
Headers size in bytes: 0  
Body size in bytes: 0  
Sample Count: 1  
Error Count: 1  
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):  
Response code: 500  
Response message: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;  
  nested exception is:  
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  
pop3s://enwarali@gmail.com@pop.googlemail.com:995/INBOX[1]  

 Response headers:


 SampleResult fields:  
ContentType:  
DataEncoding: null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mail Reader Sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859794/mail-reader-sampler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Read Gmail messages on other email clients using POP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en) article:

> Incoming Mail (POP) Server **pop.gmail.com**
>
> Requires SSL: Yes
>
> Port: 995

So try changing your `Server Host` setting to `pop.gmail.com`

Also double check the following:

1. You have enabled POP in Gmail Settings
2. You can access port 995 of pop.gmail.com server (you can check it using [telnet client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients), i.e. it isn't blocked in your OS firewall, organization, router, etc.
3. You are not blocked by Gmail for retrieving messages too fast

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more information on sending and receiving emails using JMeter

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I checked the setting, also enable allow less secure setting, but still get Connect failed;, Connection timed out error 500?